# Azure - block all traffic from outside the USA

Tags: azure

I'm having issues with Russian IP addresses trying to access various areas of my website, that do not exist. I have been hacked before with Ramsonware on AWS. How can I restrict my Azure traffic to just IP addresses in the US?

thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add a Web Application Firewall (WAF) in front of your web app. You can either use Azure Front Door or Azure Application Gateway and enable WAF, then you just need to setup the geomatch custom rule (which is currently in preview).

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/geomatch-custom-rules

Comment: You beat me to it by a few seconds :D.

Comment: my bot never fails :P